# Order of execution in Makefile

Tags: makefile

1. I created a makefile and I want to know in which order the makefile will execute the commands. Is the there any method I can use to know?

   ```
   fao: main.o high.o low.o utils.o
       gcc -o foo main.o high.o low.a utils.o
   main.o: main.c high.h utils.h
       gcc -c -o main.o main.c high.h utils.h
   high.o: high.c law.h utils.h
       gcc -c -o high.o high.c low.h utils.h
   low.o: law.c utils.h
       gcc -c -o low.o low.c utlls.h
   utils.o: utils.c utils.h
       gcc -c -o utils.o utils.c utils.h
   clean:
       -rm -f fao main.o high.o low.o utils.o
   ```
2. I am trying to understand  the behaviour of makefile.  Tell me if I am right. If I have got all the `*.c` files and the `*.h` files but no `*.o` files, in which order will the makefile execute the commands?
3. If, for example, I edit `utils.h` and I execute `make` again, what will happen then? And in which order will the make program execute the commands this time?

Comment: i suspect that you did not mean `-0` everywhere

Comment: You don't normally specify `high.h` and `utils.h` on the C compiler command line (for `main.o`, amongst others), but you do list them on the dependency lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 why do you care? Make will make in an order that obeys your dependencies

2 dont understand the question

3 if you edit utils.h all things dependent on utils.h will be remade. And then all things that depends on the remade things will be remade. In your case pretty much everything will be remade.

Note that you should not include .h files in the gcc command lines. ie this is wrong (and fix -o for you too)

```
gcc -c -0 main.o main.c high.h utils.h
```

should be just

```
gcc -c -o main.o main.c
```

You are also missing tab at the start of the gcc lines

If you want to see what make will do try `make -n` and `make -d` see https://linux.die.net/man/1/make

Comment: thank you now its all clear with make -n and make -d !